# Magento 2: Get custom category attributes by category id

Tags: magento2, category-attribute, category-id

I have category ID and need to get all custom attribute for example thumbnail image.

my code does not return all attributes

```
$category = $this->categoryRepository->get($childId, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
$category->getData();
```

Comment: Any system or exception log?

Comment: no, it returns some attributes for example id , created_at, url but not all

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your category first like this

```
use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
class ...
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $categoryRepository;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,
    ) {
        .........
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    }

     public  function getCategory()
    {
            $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());

    }
}
```

and after this load your attributes from model like this

```
$attributes = $category->getAttributes();
```

Comment: yes works, but how can I get only one attribute from this variable?

Comment: Try this  $category->_getAttribute($attributeCode);

Comment: not working ... invalid method

Comment: $category>getIsCollectionPageListing(); where IsCollectionPageListing will be your attribute name

Answer (score 0):

You can't print **getData()** because it's not part of that **categoryRepository** class. If you want to get all attributes then, you need to follow this below code:

```
$category = $this->categoryRepository->get($childId, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
$attributes = $category->getAttributes(); //It's object. So, you need to get value by foreach
foreach($attributes as $value)
{
    echo $value->getName();
}
```

If you want to get single attribute value. Then, you can get by this below code :

> For ex : echo $category->getData('name');

```
$category = $this->categoryRepository->get($childId, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
echo $category->getData('your_attribute_code');
```